# How to fix TextField value characters re-arranging when typing in jetpack compose

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

When I am entering data on the Textfield and happen to press backspace to remove the last letter, then try to type again, the text in the text field rearranges.

I have copied code from jetpack compose play ground and tried it, but it is behaving the same. Is their any fix for this?

[image: error video description]

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
  fun TextFieldDemo() {
      Column(Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
          val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
          TextField(
               value = textState.value,
               onValueChange = { textState.value = it }
          )
          Text("The textfield has this text: " + textState.value.text)
      }
   }
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, it looks like you are doing everything right. I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128), specifying the device and the installed Android version you are using, as well as a full sample project.

Comment: Hi Salvation! I can run your code fine, I don't see the problem you described and showed on the GIF image. What version of Compose are you using? Maybe it's an old one? I'm using 1.1.0-rc03, and it works fine on my emulator. Have you tried to run the app in an emulator as well?

Comment: thanks philip for the reply. i have discovered that it happens on all text Field types except type password. and i have filed a bug report.

Comment: I have tried on compose 1.0.1 and 1.0.5 the out come is still the same. using android version 6 and 7

Comment: what's the link to the bug report? we have the same issue

Comment: is looks like this one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221636606